# Android Prevent Drag and Drop to Menu Bar

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app that allows users to drag and drop some `ImageViews` within a container. The code and the screenshot are shown below. The way I did it is:

1. When a user touches down the `ImageView` (the red circle in the screenshot), it starts drag, and make the `ImageView` invisible;
2. In the parent view (the blue area) where the drag and drop is allowed, handle the `ACTION_DROP` action in `OnDragListener` to change the location when the drop happens, and make the `ImageView` visible again;
3. In the part of activity view out of the parent view, the white area, handle the `ACTION_DROP` action in `OnDragListener` to simply make the `ImageView` visible again, so that if dropped out of the container, the `ImageView` stays where it is;

Now the problem is, if the user drag and drop to the top bar (where the signal strength and battery level are shown, circled in red), or the bottom bar (where the back button is located, circled in red), no event is triggered to make the red circle visible again, so the red circle will disappear forever.

According to the documentation, the `ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` is fired when this happens, where I can make the red circle visible again. However, in my case, this event is never fired.

Can someone please help?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    findViewById(R.id.container).getRootView().setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                ((View)event.getLocalState()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgCircle).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
                    v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        rootView.findViewById(R.id.dropArea).setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    View circleView = (View)event.getLocalState();
                    if(circleView != null) {
                        circleView.setX(event.getX());
                        circleView.setY(event.getY());
                        circleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rootView.findViewById(R.id.dropArea).setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                View circleView = (View)event.getLocalState();
                if(circleView != null) {
                    circleView.setX(event.getX());
                    circleView.setY(event.getY());
                    circleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                if (!event.getResult) findViewById(R.id.imgCircle).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation says:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

> The listener must call
>   getResult() to get the value that was returned in response to
>   ACTION_DROP. If an ACTION_DROP event was not sent, then getResult()
>   returns false.

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: 
                if (!event.getResult()) { 

                }
                break;
```

You should handle your logics inside if statement.

Answer (score -1):

there is very simple issue you are facing.

ACTION_DRAG_ENDED is not fired because this action is fired when you registered a view to drag listener.
All the view that registered using **setOnDragListener()**.
for these kind of view all DragEvent Action fired.
but because your action bar view not registered using  setOnDragListener(). that why ACTION_DRAG_ENDED or any of the action is not fired for perticular view.

Summary is that if you drag and drop a view(Suppose A) on the view which register on **setOnDragListener()** listener(Suppose B). for only that view(Here B) all the action getting fired.